# print out a list of books with a for loop, c#

Tags: c#

I have a book class that holds a couple of books, with book author, publishing year and name of book. now I want to print out the books using a loop but im not sure what loop i should use. here is my code for the book class:

```
class Book
{
    public string forfattareEfternamn;
    public string forfattareFornamn;
    public string bokensTittle;
    public int lanseringsDatum;

    public string BokensTittle
    {
        get { return bokensTittle; }
        set { bokensTittle = value; }
    }
    public string ForfattareFornamn
    {
        get {return forfattareFornamn;}
        set {forfattareFornamn = value;}
    }

    public string ForfattareEfternamn
    {
        get {return forfattareEfternamn;}
        set {forfattareEfternamn = value;;}
    }

    public int LanseringsDatum
    {
        get { return lanseringsDatum; }
        set { lanseringsDatum = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3} ", forfattareEfternamn, ForfattareFornamn, bokensTittle, lanseringsDatum);

    }
}
```

and here is the code in the Main, where i have created my list of books:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
        books.Add(new Book { forfattareFornamn = "Dumas", forfattareEfternamn = "Alexandre", bokensTittle = "The Count Of Monte Cristo", lanseringsDatum = 1844 });
        books.Add(new Book { forfattareFornamn = "Clark", forfattareEfternamn = "Arthur C", bokensTittle = "Rendezvous with Rama", lanseringsDatum = 1972 });
        books.Add(new Book { forfattareFornamn = "Dumas", forfattareEfternamn = "Alexandre", bokensTittle = "The Three Musketeers", lanseringsDatum = 1844 });
        books.Add(new Book { forfattareFornamn = "Defoe", forfattareEfternamn = "Daniel", bokensTittle = "Robinson Cruise", lanseringsDatum = 1719 });
        books.Add(new Book { forfattareFornamn = "Clark", forfattareEfternamn = "Arthur C", bokensTittle = "2001: A space Odyssey", lanseringsDatum = 1968 });

    }
}
```

So, I want to use a loop that prints the books in the list on the console screen using the ToString() method (without calling ToString() explicitly)

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach(Book b in books)
    Console.WriteLine(b);
```

The ToString gets called automatically by WriteLine (ah, polymorphism...)

Comment: I wasnt sure if I should use the for loop or foreach, but this was perfect, thx!

Comment: @user2057693 both are ok actually, but this is shorter and easier to read ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use a foreach loop to loop through how many occurances of books there are in the collection. Then print them to the console.

```
foreach (Book book in books)
{
    Console.WriteLine(book.ToString()); // ToString gets called automatically so you can skip that if you want. I think it makes it a little clearer when reading it again.
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you include a reference to System.Linq in your project, you can use:

```
books.ForEach(b => Console.WriteLine(b))
```

You can even shorten this to:

```
books.ForEach(Console.WriteLine)
```

Comment: You don't need System.Linq for this.  It's a method of `List<T>` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx)